# How to divide a segmented image into classes instances?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, image-segmentation, instance-segmentation

Is there a method/algorithm to generate instances of objects from image that was segmented by the use of any image segmentation models?

For example, I have an image with one class and it was segmented in a given way, where 1s are objects of the same class and empty fields are of no class:[image]

How can I now generate list of the two objects, where list's elements for example would be positions of all the pixels inside the object (list of list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those segmented instances can be seen as [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) of the 1s. You can use the [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) or [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) algorithm to detect these components or try [SimpleBlobDetector](https://learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/) by OpenCV.

Comment: "flood fill" finally worked out for me, there is a nice implementation in scikit-image library , although I had to make a loop to go through all objects, because basic implementation can only fill one "blob" of 1s at a time